# Key search in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

EDIT: OK I wasn't aware of the double equal sign in the first code. Thank you for addressing it. I am new at Stackoverflow so I didn't know that asking debugging questions are in the "off topic" rule. Sorry.

I am stuck about something in Python. I wanted to search every letter of a 'word' in the dictionary 'result', change the value of that word to 0 if found and return 'result'.

For some reason it doesn't work; and if I search just one letter Here is the code which doesn't below:

```
result = {'a': 1, 'q': 1, 'l': 2, 'm': 1, 'u': 1, 'i': 1}
word = 'quail'

for letter in word:
    if letter in result.keys():
        result[letter] == 0

return result
```

Here is the code that works:

```
result = {'a': 1, 'q': 1, 'l': 2, 'm': 1, 'u': 1, 'i': 1}
letter = 'l'
if letter in result.keys():
    result [letter] = 0
return result
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `result[letter] == 0` are you kidding? this isn't assigning.

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ is not a problem description.

Comment: If you have code that works, why aren't you using it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as being caused by a simple typographical error, assuming that what you pasted here is what you ran.

Comment: Hello everyone, yeah I now realised that I missed an equal sign there. Thank you for pointing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result[letter] = 0
```

Your problem is in the assignment. You are comparing the variable to 0, not assigning it. When you use "==" you are asking the program if thing on left is the same as thing on right, and expecting it to return a boolean, true or false.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a double equals in the first code.

Comment: An answer would explain why that is a problem, and what it should be instead.